# Force all Urls having a query parameter in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, urlhelper

Is there a way to force all Urls built using the `UrlHelper` to include a specific parameter?
The idea would be once I set a specific parameter to always follow it on links.

I generate most of my urls using the following code: `Url.RouteUrl("MyRoute", new {myparam = 1})`

What I would like to do:
I go to `https://example.com?myparam=1`
I would like all links generated on the page to include the `myparam=1` parameter. If no param has been specified, then the url should not include it.

I am thinking on extending `UrlHelper`, overriding the `RouteUrl` method (I only use this one), extend the parameters and register this class as a service, but is seems complicated as parameters are passed as an anonymous class...

Is there any better way to reach that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a session variable or a cookie to do that, then use as required. You solution seems quite a bit riskier in something going wrong.

Comment: That is an option I had in mind, however it is mainly for debug/internal use purposes (browse the site with a specific option activated), therefore there is no big risk.

Comment: Another option is add a role or claim to indicate "debugger" or similar then it can be set up per user and switched on/off?

Comment: To be clear: the objective of this "debug" is to summarize all resources used by a specific page. It can be either logged in, or not (that is why user is not good, but cookie might be). When activating this flag, all the resources are displayed at the end of the page by the layout.